# Dynamics CRM 2013: Audit logs not showing details

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have come across an odd error I have never encountered before in the audit logs:

[image]

As you can see there are no details displayed but rather just an image

When I click on a specific line I only get this:

[image]

I haven't the faintest idea of where to start looking

I am a system administrator in the system so I don't think it's a permissions issue.

I can also confirm that there are real values in the system where the audit logs display that image instead of a value.

It seems to be a widespread issue across almost every entity in the system too.

**EDIT:**

I have looked in the audit management logs and found this:

[image]

I guess this indicates that no logs have been deleted?

Comment: Have you cleared audit trials at any stage, the image shown is a image shown of a broken link (value undetermined) ?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when auditing was switched off and on again. From that moment the system cannot guarantee that the audit trail shown is complete and therefore it displays a torn page symbol.